# Pagination page button doesn't update the embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been working on this code and it works now but the embed doesn't update and the paginate function works just fine in my other codes... Any way to fix this?

```js
const paginate = require('../../functions/paginate')
const words = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'frog', 'giraffe', 'hallway', 'iridescent', 'jockey', 'kangaroo', 'language', 'midnight', 'nightmare', 'otter', 'philanthrope', 'question', 'reindeer', 'scarecrow', 'trousers', 'unity', 'vinegar', 'winter', 'xylophone', 'yolk', 'zoom']
        
    const ar = args
      if(!ar) return;

    let list = words.filter(m=> m.includes(ar))
 //     if (list.length > 10) list = list.slice(0, 9).join('\n');
      let lists = list.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
          .map(r => r)
          .map((r, i) => `**${i + 1}** - ${r}`)
          .slice(0, 20)
          .join("\n");
   if(!list) return interaction.editReply(`Unable to find a word for ${ar}`)
      
        let embeds = [];

          list.forEach(() => {
            embeds.push(
            new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}))
            .setDescription(`${lists}`)
            .setColor("#000000")
          )
          })
    
        paginate(message, embeds, {
          timeout: 60
        });
```

paginate.js file

```js
const {MessageActionRow, MessageButton} = require("discord.js");

const paginate = async (message, pages, options = {}) => {

    if(!message) throw new Error('No message was provided');
    if(!pages || pages.length === 0) return;

    options = {
        timeout: options.timeout ?? 60,
        footer: options.footer ?? `${message.guild.name}`,
        split: options.split ?? "/" 
    };

    let button1 = new MessageButton({
        customId: "back",
        emoji: '<:lla:989025260269621278>',
        style: "SECONDARY"
    });

    let button2 = new MessageButton({
        customId: "next",
        emoji: '<:rra:989025169274191894>',
        style: "SECONDARY"
    });

    let page = 0;

    const row = new MessageActionRow({components: [button1, button2]});
    const curPage = await message.channel.send({
        embeds: [pages[page].setFooter({text: `${options.footer} ${page + 1} ${options.split} ${pages.length}`})],
        components: [row],
    });

    const filter = (i) =>
        i.customId === button1.customId ||
        i.customId === button2.customId;

    const collector = curPage.createMessageComponentCollector({
        filter,
        time: options.timeout * 1000,
    });

    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
        switch(i.customId) {
            case button1.customId:
                page = page > 0 ? --page : pages.length - 1;
                break;
            case button2.customId:
                page = page + 1 < pages.length ? ++page : 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        await i.deferUpdate();
        await i.editReply({
            embeds: [pages[page].setFooter({text: `${options.footer} ${page + 1} ${options.split} ${pages.length}`})],
            components: [row],
        });
        collector.resetTimer();
    });

    collector.on("end", (_, reason) => {
        if(reason !== "messageDelete") {
            const disabledRow = new MessageActionRow({
                components: [button1.setDisabled(true), button2.setDisabled(true)]
            });
            curPage.edit({
                embeds: [pages[page].setFooter({text: `${options.pageText} ${page + 1} ${options.split} ${pages.length}`})],
                components: [disabledRow],
            }).catch(console.log);
        }
    });

    return curPage;
};

module.exports = paginate;
```

Its working in my other codes and I don't get any errors either when I run the code above I can't really tell what the problem is

Comment: show us your paginate.js file's content too

Comment: I added the paginate's file now. Is there any changes needed in the file?